# Delegate with UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, delegates

I'm trying to hide a label in my `TableViewCell` when I go into "editing mode". So I created a protocol:

```
// UITableView Class
@protocol CellDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)toggleOpacityOff
- (void)toggleOpacityOn
@end

//in @interface
@property (nonatomic, strong) id <CellDelegate> delegate;
```

I implemented these methods in the `UITableViewCell` class and passed the delegate to the cell class:

```
// cellForRowAtIndexPath method
CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

self.delegate = cell;

return cell;
```

But when I run this the methods apply only to the top most cell in the TableView.
Why is that and how can I fix it? Many thanks! :)

Comment: If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, you have a mistake in your delegate code.

Comment: I believe delegate should be `weak` instead of `strong`.

Comment: @Zhang doesn't solve the problem..

Comment: Didn't say it does, just pointing that out :D

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to fix this by changing the following line to set the correct delegate (remember that delegates should always be **weak**, not strong!):

```
self.delegate = cell;
```

to line:

```
cell.delegate = self;
```

**The longer explanation is that delegate would not be the correct way to achieve this.**

*Delegates are meant to message back some specific action or information, this way your cell would actually tell the delegate that it had something togged on or off. This makes no sense, because you are looking to toggle something off.*

The correct way of achieving your goal is to create a `UITableViewCell` subclass and implement those methods on a cell (`toggleOpacityOff` and `toggleOpacityOn`). Or even better create a specific cell property and override it's setter. Then you call this method in `UITableViewDelegate` method `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. See the following example:

```
@interface MyCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic) BOOL opacity;

@end

@implementation MyCell

- (void)setOpacity:(BOOL)opacity
{
    if (opacity)
    {
        // Set opacity to ON
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        // Set opacity to OFF
    }
}

@end
```

To loop through all cells:

```
- (void)updateCells
{
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [self tableView:self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]; i++)
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];

        MyCell *cell = (MyCell *)[self tableView:self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.opacity = YES; 
    }
}
```

In addition to this, it might be wise to remember this state in your model, so it remains correct when cells are reused (when scrolling).

Comment: but my cell class doesn't have the delegate property, and infact I do need it to be `self.delegate = cell` because my protocol is in my TableView class.

Comment: But the thing is, that I need to call this from somewhere else in the `UITableViewClass`, I have a button that toggles the editing mode on and off and I need to call it from there

Comment: Yes, you can. Get your cell with: `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method and call `setOpacity` on the specific cell. If you need more, just create your `NSIndexPath` objects.

Comment: What kind of NSIndexPath objects do I need to create if I need to apply this to all of the cells? `CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *) [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(?)`

Comment: how can I do it for all the cells?

Comment: Just do a loop to the number of cells.

Comment: Can you please give me an example code? I don't really understand the way you mean to do it...

Answer (score 0):

Just keep some BOOL in your tableview class like isInEditMode. Then you add something like this into your cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
if (isInEditMode)
    [cell.myText setHidden:YES];
else 
    [cell.myText setHidden:NO];
```

And once you want to switch into edit mode you just do this

```
self.isInEditMode = YES;
[self.tableview reloadData]
```